# fully preemptive kernel and process stuck in D state

Tags: linux, kernel, real-time, scheduler, preemptive

This is more of a theoretical question as I'm trying to understand how the kernel scheduler works (but also I've been having hung_task issues while mid-priority RT tasks are running - and also there are swapper processes in the CPU dumps). I am using the kernel with the RT patch (fully preemptive kernel).

1. If the process goes into a D state (due to a sys_read from RAM, e.g. from procfs), is it possible for it to be preempted by higher priority RT tasks (maybe multiple times) so it will remain into the D state and then resume reading? I am unsure how this works if there is RAM read in question.
2. So, what happens next, the process stuck in a D state is actually in uninterruptible sleep, and is it waiting to be rescheduled if it is preempted? Can it be rescheduled on a different CPU? Especially if there are swapper tasks present, wouldn't they do something to resume the process that was in D state?

I am a bit confused by all this, as I have processes reading just from RAM, and somehow other tasks try to get rt-mutex locks from it and then I get hung_task issue. But there are always some (seemingly) idle CPU cores. Why would a RAM read take so long? Sometimes RCU thread also gets hung while waiting for a lock from a process doing a sys_read from procfs.

I know it's a lot of questions, but I need to connect the pieces of the puzzle in my head somehow. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Process stuck in D state is off the runqueue and thus can't be preempted (no matter his state). Uninterruptible sleep refers to it not being able to be woken up by signals, and has nothing to do with preemption.